# What is the correct way to obtain access to the WP_oEmbed object?

Tags: globals, oembed

I know that `WP_oEmbed` is a class used by WordPress to handle oEmbeds. Is this available as a global or should I create a new instance of it?

**Update**: I have found a function called `_wp_oembed_get_object()` which says in the documentation:

> This function’s access is marked private. This means it is not intended for use by plugin or theme developers, only in other core functions. It is listed here for completeness.

**Update 2**: FYI, I plan on calling a number of its methods for something I am working on.

**Update 3:** For now, at least, I'm assuming `$oembed = new WP_oEmbed();` is the best practice.

Comment: Why do you need access to it? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @JacobPeattie I have updated my question to cover this.